# Como evitar multiple inserts no banco dados

Tags: php, mysql

Ola gostaria de saber como posso usar o php para evitar o adicionamento de um mesmo item em um banco de dados em uma pagina de salvamento que adiciona os nomes das subcategorias caso atualize o navegador.

Sendo que não posso usar no banco o Unique na tabela subcategoria no campo nome pois isso me impossibilitaria de poder usar o mesmo nome caso ele esteja filiado a outra categoria.

Segue abaixo as duas tabelas.

**Tabela Categoria**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categoria` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nome` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `modo` enum('UNICO','MULTIPLO') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'UNICO',
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `categoriaUnica` (`categoria_url`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nomeUnico` (`nome`),
  KEY `colunasIndexadas` (`id`,`categoria_url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**Tabela subcategoria**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subcategoria` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subcategoria_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `temporada` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `nome` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cat` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `semana` enum('Selecionar Semana','Domingo','Segunda-Feira','Terca-Feira','Quarta-Feira','Quinta-Feira','Sexta-Feira','Sábado') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Selecionar Semana',
  `ativadorOn` enum('ON','OFF') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'OFF',
  `sinopse` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Completo','Incompleto','Andamento','Pausado','Lançamento') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Andamento',
  `genero` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `genero_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `numeroMedias` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `autor` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `acessos` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_nome` varchar(355) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_tipo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_data_cad` date NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_hora_cad` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `colunasIndexadas` (`id`,`cat`,`categoria_url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Parece-me que você tem um problema de normalização de banco de dados. Se vc mudar o nome de uma subcategoria ou sua url por exemplo, vc precisaria atualizar toda a tabela de categoria com os novos dados. Neste caso teriamos um relacionamento 1 para N. Se vc deseja utilizar uma categoria alinhada a mais de uma sucategoria, ou seja uma relação N para N, vc precisaria de uma tabela auxiliar para resolver esta situação, agrupando o id da tabela categoria e o id da tabela subcategoria. Assim você evitaria a duplicidade caso já houver uma correspondência mesmo que você saia da aplicação e retorne

Comment: @Rodrigo poste o código de suas páginas, a de cadastro e a que insere os dados no banco.

Comment: Não se precipite em aceitar a primeira resposta como absoluta, nem sempre é a solução para seu problema, o correto é colocar como Unique o ( id da categoria + nome subcategoria ), e tratar o erro "23000"  exemplo: UNIQUE INDEX `nome_da_unique` (`cat`, `nome`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pode utilizar tokens de acesso.
2. a 1 e 2 pagina deverao ter session_start(); no incio e passar um token com um numero gerado aleatorio ou um codigo gerado aleatoriamente, fazendo impossivel de aceder a pagina novamente sem ir a 1 pagina!
3. A 1 pagina e onde o utilizador ve adiciona coisas ao carrinho (por exeplo" na 2 pagina o onde ocorre o processo de adiciona na base de dados!

Como gerar a token na 1 pagina?

```
<?php
session_start();
function geraToken()
{
return rand(1, 1000)."".rand(1, 1000); // Gerar numeros aleatorios
}
$_SESSION['token'] = geraToken();
?>
```

Como utilizar o token na 2 pagina?

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
    die("Acesso negado!");
}
//Adicione aki o resto da 2 pagina...
//...

// NO fim do processo adicione isto
$_SESSION['token'] = ""; // Fazendo a token invalida e impedindo o refresh da pagina!
?>
```

Comment: No caso pra poder realizar o salvamento e obrigatório no meu casso passar pelo adicionador primeiro para ir ao salve certo caso de refrash na pagina do salve essa função retorna acesso negado certo ? E a parte para adicionar no final seria no caso apos o código de insert certo ?

Comment: certo ;) a token e removida depois do processo do insert

Comment: Ata desta forma então ele desvalida o numero gerado no rand entendi agora grato pela ajuda. Só que no caso eu uso session pra locação mais ai só estaria des validando somente o token certo ?

Comment: @Hardcorder, é um tanto fora do comum, indicar soluções para [CSRF](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) pra evitar duplicação em banco de dados.

Comment: @Mandrake Mas porque meteu -1 voto? nao entendi. se a solucao esta ai a funcionar perfeitamente! E tem seguranca. Eu nao so respondi a questao como lhe dei uma dica de como usar Tokens.

Comment: @Hardcorder, isso não é solução para evitar duplicação, se fosse um select count, ou índice na tabela, você tinha meu +1, mas isso ai nunca foi solução e nunca será!

Answer (score 3):

Na função Unique Key, você pode colocar quantos campos quiser para manter na tabela, a linha como sendo `Única`

**Exemplo com mais de um campo**

```
UNIQUE KEY `nomeIdUnique` (`nome`,`cat`)
```

Em sua tabela

```
CREATE TABLE `subcategoria` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `subcategoria_url` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `temporada` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `nome` char(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `cat` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `semana` enum('Selecionar Semana','Domingo','Segunda-Feira','Terca-Feira','Quarta-Feira','Quinta-Feira','Sexta-Feira','Sábado') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Selecionar Semana',
  `ativadorOn` enum('ON','OFF') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'OFF',
  `sinopse` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('Completo','Incompleto','Andamento','Pausado','Lançamento') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Andamento',
  `genero` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `genero_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `numeroMedias` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `autor` char(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `acessos` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_nome` varchar(355) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_tipo` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_data_cad` date NOT NULL,
  `arquivo_hora_cad` time NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nomeIdUnique` (`nome`,`cat`),
  KEY `colunasIndexadas` (`id`,`cat`,`categoria_url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Desta forma nunca ira se repetir, e caso esteja usando PDO, não precisa enviar o erro para o arquivo de log

```
try {

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode !== 23000) {
        //log
    }
}
```

Comment: No caso estou usando MySQL.

Comment: @Rodrigo, PDO é uma biblioteca do PHP de abstração de banco de dados, como a mysql_* e mysqli_*

Comment: Eu sei dissp ja estou passando tudo pra mysqli